# How to set mouseover display delay

Tags: javascript, delay, detection, onmouseover

I'm using mouseover effect on a table list to show content of lesson on hover.
However, as it's in table, it's "changing too fast", when going from one row to another, that is why I would like to put some delay on the mouseover effect.

My code currently looks like this :

```
onmouseover="show('id')" onmouseout="hide('id')">
```

How to make a small delay ?

Comment: Has it something to do with php? anyway, are you using any library such as jQuery or are you using pure javascript? If you're not, you may take a look at the setTimeout javascript function and use it either on the show function and the hide function :)

Comment: You might want to try to put some type of sleep, check this it could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-do-i-do-if-i-want-a-javascript-version-of-sleep

Comment: you can set a timer via javascript? Did you look into that?

Answer (score 1):

A non jQuery solution, for reference:

```
<script>

    var show=function(x)
    {
        setTimeout(
            function()
            {
                do the stuff...
            },
            200
        );
    };

    var hide=function(x)
    {
        setTimeout(
            function()
            {
                do the other stuff...
            },
            200
        );
    };

</script>
<div onmouseover="show('id')"  onmouseout="show('id')"></div>
```

Basically, I've defined `show` and `hide` as functions which create anonymous functions that do the actual showing and hiding and then run them after a 200ms delay using `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

An awesome plugin by brain if you use jquery to control your hover actions and timers.
http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

or you can just use vannilla javascript to set timers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with jQuery's show and hide methods you can simply put the desired duration in ms between the brackets:

```
<div onmouseover="$('#id').show(600)" onmouseout="$('#id').hide(600)">
    some content
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, i would like to use this one, however i struggle because my code currently looks like this (not simply "id") :

onmouseover="'<?php echo $courseinfo->id;?>'" onmouseout="hide('<?php echo $courseinfo->id;?>')">

Comment: Oh that shouldn't be a problem. PHP statements are preprocessed on the server side. Just write something like <div onmouseover="$('<?php echo $couseinfo -> id; ?>').show(600)" onemouseout= "$('<?php echo $couseinfo -> id; ?>').hide(600)". And please mark the answer as correct if there are no more questions.

Comment: I used your exact code, but mouseover is not working anymore. I guess the PHP statement is not processed then, because when i inspect html code rendered, i get :
onmouseover="$('38').show(600)"

Comment: Managed to solve, even when showing exact same in code, mouseover is not working :( I guess there is conflict Jquery/PHP ?

Comment: Should the detail box be displayed after a certain period of time, then use the solution above [link] http://stackoverflow.com/a/23247335/3095875 or should there be an animation (so the content fades in slower)?